# Old cartoon movie or series: robots walking down a tilting corridor to get "sacrificed"

Tags: story-identification, robots

I just remembered a scene from a somewhat old sci-fi cartoon series or movie but Google only brought me here so I'll give it a try.

What I can remember: a lot of robots walking down a tunnel or corridor in line, chanting some name or something (of their god?). After they stopped, the corridor began tilting forward, so the robots began to slide down the corridor, slowly becoming a hole.

My memory of it is very vague, but I think the corridor had a half-round ceiling like a car tunnel and was made out of grey bricks. The robots were grey or blue with noodle-like arms and legs (think Bender from *Futurama*). I think I can remember that there were big and small (child) robots and the protagonist tried to save them. It was a somewhat sad scene.

What I mean with old: at least pre-90s, I think maybe 70s or 80s. As I said my memory of it is pretty vague, I was only a child then.

Additionally, I think the art style was maybe similar to *Captain Future* or *Akira*.

The robots I remember where more cult like, they were waiting to finally go into this corridor and meet their maker I think. Like they where sent there to die.

Comment: I don't know about the described scene, but does this look familiar? https://i.imgur.com/OFvyAJw.png

Comment: @npst: mhh dont think thats it, from the picture at least, whats the name of it?

Comment: That's from "Il était une fois… l’Espace" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time..._Space

Comment: The robots in the most likely episodes from _Once Upon a Time... Space_ do look like they could be from your description but looking at the relevant episodes I can't see the scene you describe. [Image of said robots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwGqv.png).

Comment: i remember them more like in the picture of npst. i looked up once upon a time space on youtube and i remember stuff of it, but i dont know if the scene i mentiones is from this show. as i said its pretty vague. the robots i remember where more cult like, they where waiting to be finnaly go into this corridor and meet their maker i think. like they where sent there to die. like i said it was a rather sad scene. is there a episode where old robots get scrapped for example? (added the description to op)